# Expanding raster within mask by interpolating it with boundaries set to 0

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, masking

I'm having a hard time trying to **expand a raster within a mask**. Here are some details about my case:

I'm working with **glacier ice thickness rasters**, which happen to be smaller than the real size of the glaciers, specified by a **vector polygon** which I'm using as a **mask**. **My goal is to expand the ice thickness raster within the polygon by interpolating the raster with the borders of the polygon which should be 0 (meaning no ice)**. I've tried to address this problem in multiple ways, and I have ended up converting the raster to points and the borders to points with value 0 and merging both layers. Here is what I have so far tested:

[image: Glacier ice thickness raster converted to points]

When I try to interpolate the points using different interpolation tools I'm getting this error message: *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details*

I have also tried doing the same but directly with a raster file (with the ice thickness raster added surrounded by 0 values), and trying to interpolate it with the glacier polygon mask.

[image] [image]

I've been using GRASS' r.surf.idw tool, but I can't get it to work. Despite having the raster file and the polygon file with the same CRS, I see a warning label on top of my screen saying *Warning: The projection of the chosen layer is not the same as canvas projection! The selected extent might not be what was intended*.

The results always look like this:

[image]

Anyone has any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: What CRS are both your layers AND the project set to. If you changed the CRS of any layers, did you save them with a new one or use the reproject tool?

Comment: This seems like a very common situation: e.g. bathymetry raster rarely stretch all the way to the coasts. As it is clear (just like in the above question) that the values would be expanding outwards to reach a value of 0 at the polygon border, there should be an efficient way to accomplish this. Maybe now, 5 years later, someone has a good idea how it do it, so I have asked a new question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/457979/223215

Comment: See also this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/457998/223215